# How to correlate Oracle server session id with connection object in application code

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

Is it possible to correlate the Oracle server session id with the connection object in the application code?

Comment: You can always execute a query to get the session id

Comment: Yes, I can get the current SID for my session with this query  
    `select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual;`  
I was hoping for a way without code changes.

Comment: Without code changes?  How do you expect code to provide something different/additional without changing it?  What am I missing here?

Comment: The motivation is to find code that might not be closing the connections. I did find something interesting. It appears that it is possible to set some properties on the `OracleConnection` object that translates into columns in the `v$session` view. `ActionName` becomes `ACTION`, `ClientId` becomes `CLIENT_IDENTIFIER`, and `ModuleName` becomes `MODULE`. I will utilize this in collaboration with the `StackFrame` class to provide more information about where the connections were created.

Comment: @EdStevens, it is not unusual to be able to add configuration that will enable log output for instance, so yes, I do expect code to provide more information without coding ;-)

Comment: That would depend on the framework of the application

Comment: @4thex - you might find the [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_appinf.htm) useful in this regard.